# Web fonts fails to apply in newsletter (GMAIL , Yahoo Mail , Outlook, Hotmail etc) working on browser though

Tags: html, css, email, webfonts, newsletter

I have a newsletter where I use web font *Proxima Nova Extra Bold* and *Proxima Nova Alt Regular*. When I open the newsletter layout on browser the font appears fine for all text. But when the same newsletter is opened in Gmail or Yahoo or other mail client the font is not applied to text.

Broswer Layout Screenshot (Font appears perfect ):[image]

Gmail Layout Screenshot (Font is not taken) : [image]

Here is the way I have applied the font to newsletter file :
        Inside `<head>` Tag :

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url("http://serverdomainname/emailtemplatefonts.css");
body{font-family:ProximaNova-AltRegular !important;}
        </style>
```

Styling via inline css

```
<span style="padding:25px;text-align:center;display:block;font-size:14px;font-family:ProximaNova-AltRegular">Discover attractions, restaurants, nightlife, and accomodations around the world. Use specialized filters in your search to find free museums, family friendly restaurants, weird and wonderful hotels, and much more. </span>
```

Here is the css of font file included :

```
@font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-AltRegular';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('http://sitedomain.com/assets/fonts/proxima_nova_alt/ProximaNovaAltRegular.woff2') format('woff2');}



@font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-Extrabold';
font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
src: url('http://sitedomain.com/assets/fonts/proxima_nova_bold/ProximaNovaExtrabold.woff2') format('woff2');}
```

Comment: Might be an issue with not using HTTPS. You could check your developer tools (F12 in browser) for errors about this. If that is the problem the solution would be to start using https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many email clients do not support web fonts. And even if they do you have to jump through quite a few hoops, like moving the `style` tag between `head` and `body` for example.

Here is a summary on web font support for various email clients:

https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/

Prepare for quite a few hacks and consider falling back to standard fonts (but prefer not to use images because of the limitations this places on the accessibility of your email).

Answer (score 1):

Gmail and other email clients will strip out the `<style>` tag in the HTML. I'm not aware of any way around this. If you want/need to use a custom font for a header or otherwise, the most reliable way is to insert an image of the font, unfortunately.

Comment: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/gmail_web_app_allows_style It's an old article but it might be true, if so adding styles to the body tag should work/

Comment: I don't think adding styles to the body tag is the problem - this could be done inline anyway, e.g. `<body style="font-family:XXX;">`. The issue is the `@import` of the web font, which is stripped out. Thanks for the article though, I didn't know you could do that. I just tested it now and you can add styles to generic selectors, but `@import` statements will not work.

Answer (score 0):

[**Most email clients don't support web fonts, and no popular webmail services do**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Even though you're referencing Proxima Nova, the font you're actually seeing in Gmail/Yahoo is the default system sans-serif (since you have no fallback fonts in your font stack)

Web font support in email clients [isn't great](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/), so fallback system fonts are important. You can reference web fonts using the [`<link href=''>` tag](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/) instead of `@import` to increase your coverage a little.